# How do I create a document field only if it doesn't already exist?

Tags: mongodb, rust, bson

I would like to add a field to a document if it doesn't exist already but not update it if it does. Using mongodb directly I would use:

```
db.foo.update({'_created_by': {$exists : false}}, {$set: {'_created_by': 'x'}})
```

However, I am in Rust and my current code (using [bson::document's insert](https://docs.rs/bson/latest/bson/document/struct.Document.html#method.insert)) overwrites the field if it already exists:

```
doc.insert(format!("{}._created_by", key), bson!("x"));
```

How can I achieve the `{$exists : false}` part in Rust?

Comment: ... where is any relevant info on what `update_doc` is? Like what crate do you use to accessthe database? What type is it? In short please provide a [mre]!

Comment: @cafce25 I added a link to the method I used. Please excuse the missing clarity, I thought this is a well-known function.

Comment: `format!("{}._created_by")` is not valid Rust, it's missing an argument for the `{}` placeholder. As for your problem you might want to check the [documentation](https://docs.rs/bson/latest/bson/document/struct.Document.html#method.contains_key) for methods that check for a key existing, in combination with the `if` language construct it should provide facilities to do what you want.

Comment: @cafce25 I fixed the `format!()` issue, it was just a typo but that is not really what the question is about. I did check the documentation and I also found the function you linked. However, the documentation clearly specifies that while `insert()` is for `Documents`, `contains_key()` is for `Maps`. I looked for a similar function like `contains_field()` for `Documents` but I couldn't find one. That is why I asked this question. Based on your answer I assume there is no natural way of doing this and I have to manually check if the field exists, yes?

Comment: `Document` *is* a (Hash-)map, that's what this function is implemented on after all. (It's also written at the very top of that documentations page.) And yes, `contains_key` is the natural way of checking if a key exists, `if` is the natural way to do things conditionally.

Comment: @cafce25 I think it would be better if they would have consistent naming in their function descriptions but good to know! That is a good answer to my question, so if you move it from a comment to an answer, I'll accept it.